# Editing a master document and not overwriting everything in individual "versions"?

Tags: version-control

Problem: How to edit a master copy of a document and push changes to a large (approx. 1000) number of individually personalized documents without overwriting all personal changes?

```
Example:
```

> "Hello World" is changed to "Hello World!" which would need to change
>
> "Hello_World"
>   **"Hello World"**
>   *"Hello World"*
>
> to the following:
>
> "Hello_World!"
>   **"Hello World!"**
>   *"Hello World!"*

I have looked at Version Control Software as it seems to be the closest thing to my goal. Git, Google Docs, and several others have all been reviewed and are not quite what I need. I am not unrealistic in thinking this would be a hobby project; I realize what a large undertaking it would be to write something that would accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to solve a problem created by mixing content and style together.  Webpages (good ones anyway) solve this problem by using cascading style sheets to decide style while content is kept in html (or xml, or json, or...).  By separating these two concerns they can change independent of each other.

Indirection can also help.  If the string for "Hello World" is defined in one place and simply referenced in other places, that present it differently, then you only have to change it in that one defining place.

If, however, multiple instances of, "hello world", are already scattered about the document, and you don't feel like introducing some form of indirection, then tools like regular expressions, search and replace, and simply typing can solve this problem better than version control.  What version control helps with is blending your changes with the changes of others and keeping a history of older versions.

Comment: CandiedOrange, thank you for your response. I feel as if I did not clarify myself and that would be due, in part, to my use of hello world as an example. Terribly sorry for that. I need to have control over a master document that I can push updates out from to an entire business. Of the 1000~ people working there, everyone of them has a hard copy of this document with notes and such that need to be transferred to a digital copy. To clarify: Is there a way for me to push updates (once everyone transfers everything to digital) and not wipe out all personal changes? I hope this helps. Thanks!!

Comment: @BeauGriffis: Yes, that is possible by storing the notes separately from the document (with some indication in the note storage where in the document that note should be shown). The fact that it is stored separately does not mean that you can't show an annotated document to your users.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau That's true. I'll try looking at my problem from that angle instead. Thanks for the tip!